# Proof explanation: Why we can select unit vectors $z_n\in M_n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $(F,\langle\cdot\mid\cdot\rangle)$.

> - Let $T\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ and assume that there exists sequences of **unit** vectors $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ in $F$ such that
>     $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\lambda,\;\lim_{n\to \infty}\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle= \mu,$$
>     with $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are two distinct complex numbers.
> - Let $M_n$ be a subspace spanned by $x_n$ and $y_n$ and $P_n$ be a projection of $F$ onto ${M_n}$. Consider $T_n=P_nTP_n$.
>
> Why we can select **unit** vectors $z_n\in M_n$ such that $\langle T z_n\mid z_n\rangle$ is a convex combination of $\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle$ and $\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a non-trivial result called the Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem. The set 
$$
W(T)=\{\langle Tx,x\rangle:\ \|x\|=1\}
$$
is usually called the *numerical range* of $T$. The Toeplitz-Hausdorff Theorem, proven a hundred  years ago (exactly, it was in 1918), states that $W(T)$ is convex.

If $P_n $ is the orthogonal projection (and not just "a" projection) onto $M_n $, then you apply Toeplitz-Hausdorff to the operator $P_nTP_n $ acting on $M_n $ and use that $\langle T_nx_n,x_n\rangle=\langle P_nTP_nx_n,x_n\rangle $.

Comment: "Non-obvious", perhaps, since it took fifty years to find a [short elementary proof](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-01/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9/S0002-9939-1970-0262849-9.pdf).

Comment: And now much shorter than Gustafson's are known. Even then, I would still use the word "non-trivial" for the result.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you for your answer. It can be seen that  $\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle,\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle\in W(T_n)$ which is convex so we can select unit vectors $z_n\in F$ such that $\langle T z_n\mid z_n\rangle$ is a convex combination of $\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle$ and $\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle$. My question is: why $W(T_n)$ can be written as follows:
$$W(T_n):=\{\langle T_n x\mid x\rangle;\;x \in M_n\;\;\text{with}\;\|x\|=1\}?$$ Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't think it can be written like that.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Since $T_n$ acts on $M_n$, so it should be written as $$W(T_n):=\{\langle T_n x\mid x\rangle;\;x \in M_n\;\;\text{with}\;\|x\|=1\}.$$
Where is my wrong? Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Since $\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\langle T_n x_n\mid x_n\rangle$ and $\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle=\langle T_n y_n\mid y_n\rangle$ with $\|x_n\|=\|y_n\|=1$, then $\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle,\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle\in W(T_n)$ which is convex. Therefore $t\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle+(1-t)\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle\in W(T_n)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Hence we can select unit vectors $z_n\in M_n$ such that $\langle T z_n\mid z_n\rangle=t\langle T x_n\mid x_n\rangle+(1-t)\langle T y_n\mid y_n\rangle$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Is it correct what I write? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It looks like I didn't see the  $n $ in $T_n $.